# SQL Injection vulnerability using int parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-injection

Most of the time I access data using stored procedures but at times I use statements which I believe are not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Below is an example I use

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            int  CatID = Request["CatID"];

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                getDetails(CatID);
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private DataTable getDetails( int CatID)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            string strSql = "SELECT * FROM TableXYZ WHERE CatID = "+CatID ;
            ds = DataProvider.Connect_Select(strSql);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I filter my input or query string and then I call `getDetails` function and pass `CatID` as parameter to the function & then to SQL statement. Since this is an integer type data is this code vulnerable to SQL injection?

I want to clear my doubt so that I don't use SQL statement like this.

Comment: It's not vulnerable to injection but you should use a parameter anyway for the benefits of easier query plan caching.

Comment: I would always be very cautious about appending content from the user directly to the SQL, unless you filter it heavily (for example in this case, you could do an Int.TryParse(CatID) first to make sure it's just a number, which helps you avoid crashing if they mess up). Even then, why bother filtering it and having to worry about that when you can simply use SqlParameters?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: "plain SQL strings" can just as well have their query plans cached. @Tobberoth: Why do an `Int.Parse(CatID)`? CatID is already (guaranteed to be!) an `int` (see method signature).

Comment: @RobIII Did I say they can't? *you should use a parameter anyway for the benefits of **easier** query plan caching.*

Comment: @ta.speot.is Sorry, my bad, read it wrong.

Comment: @Tabberoth, For this reason i am using `int  CatID = Request["CatID"];`  if it is not int it will then generate error i agree i can use tryParse also.. This will filter my input or this can he hacked anyway i a not sure?

Comment: Doesn't sql remember execution plan of most frequently executed queries. No doubt we can get better performance using Store Procedures...

Comment: Using `Int.Parse()` won't cost you anything, but if someone in future decides that the `Id` actually needs to be a `String` it may save your ass.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, it's not a good practice to format a query string directly. [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
class is designed right for your purposes - to simplify query building and prevent SQL injections in full

Answer (score 4):

Since CatID is an `int`, no, in this case you're not vulnerable to SQL injection. But the path you've chosen is a slippery slope and, someday, prone to SQL injection when refactoring or changing your code. It's better to get into the habit of using parameterized queries and sticking with it.

I can wholehartedly suggest you try [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) (which is available as a Nuget package(; this will greatly simplify things and you won't have to change that much for it's benefits.

Your code will then become somthing like:

```
myConnection.Query<Customer>("SELECT * FROM TableXYZ WHERE CatID = @catid", new { catid = CatID });
```

Comment: I prefer Store procedure for better execution plan... I was just wondering if above example is vulnerable to sql injection taken into consideration input is being filter as `int  CatID = Request["CatID"];` I appreciate you suggestion i will look into `Dapper`

Comment: But you could probably still pass something like `42 OR 1=1` and then basically get back all rows from `TableXYZ`... concatenating together your SQL is **always** a bad idea!

Comment: @marc_s: I assume you're replying to KnowledgeSeeker because with `Dapper`, if that's what you're referring to, this will be handled (e.g. correctly parameterized) for you. Also, in the original question `CatID` is of type `int` so you wouldn't be able to pass `42 OR 1=1` but KnowledgeSeeker seems to be changing the game rules after the game has started with his reply above yours (where CatID is still of type `int` though, so again. he'd be safe as long as he's not using `var` or `string`) and making sure (when using `var` for example) that the parameter is parsed as int.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker SQL Server won't generate a better execution plan because you're using a stored procedure. It's not like "oh, a stored procedure ... I'd better do good this time."